In mobile iOS apps should the bottom tabs remain visible when navigating to nested screens?
I can't seem to find apple's human interface guidelines regarding this...
My app has the usual bottom tabs that reveal four main sections. One of these sections is a list view which shows a list of user personas. In my app users can customize their experience by creating different profiles which I call "personas". Anyway, when they click on the cards in this list view they are taken to the persona detail screen which shows more info about that particular persona inside a form which they can use to make changes.
My question is, should the bottom tabs remain visible at the bottom of this details screen (like it does for the list screen) or should the details screen appear on top of the bottom tabs? What's the best practice here?

Apple has this to say about the topic (emphasis theirs):

Make sure the tab bar is visible when people navigate to different sections of your app. If you hide the tab bar, people can forget which area of the app they’re in. The exception is when a modal view covers the tab bar, because a modal is temporary and self-contained.

Apple don't seem to be very consistent with this guideline themselves, though. In the App Store, articles (in the Today tab) open over the top of the tab bar, but links on all the other tabs generally leave it visible. Browsing categories in the Apps tab happens in a navigation view (leaving the tab bar visible), but browsing categories in the Arcade tab opens a modal overlay (hiding the tab bar).
In your case, it's up to you to decide if the view you're referring to is appropriately "temporary" and "self-contained", or if users would benefit more from being able to navigate away.

By experience, it is quite annoying when the tab bar disappears in some screens and there's no other way to navigate to the features of the other tabs, especially if you end up in situation where you have to navigate back several times to get back to a screen with the tab bar visible. So any modals covering the full screen should not have internal navigation, or have some way to dismiss them.
